# View body is called although its @Binding has not changed

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

SwiftUI promise is to call View’s `body` only when needed to avoid invalidating views whose State has not changed.
However, there are some cases when this promise is not kept and the View is updated even though its state has not changed.

Example:

```
struct InsideView: View {
   @Binding var value: Int
   // …
}
```

Looking at that view, we’d expect that its body is called when the `value` changes. However, this is not always true and it depends on how that binding is passed to the view.

When the view is created this way, everything works as expected and `InsideView` is not updated when `value` hasn’t changed.

```
@State private var value: Int = 0
InsideView(value: $value)
```

In the example below, `InsideView` will be incorrectly updated even when `value` has not changed. It will be updated whenever its container is updated too.

```
var customBinding: Binding<Int> {
   Binding<Int> { 100 } set: { _ in }
}
InsideView(value: customBinding)
```

---

Can anyone explain this and say whether it's expected? Is there any way to avoid this behaviour that can ultimately lead to performance issues?

Here's a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcjzrdyacqfz4pj/BindingUpdates.zip?dl=0) if anyone wants to play with it.
And here's a full code if you just want to paste it to your project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var tab = 0
    
    @State private var count = 0
    
    @State private var someValue: Int = 100
    var customBinding: Binding<Int> {
        Binding<Int> { 100 } set: { _ in }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Tab", selection: $tab) {
                Text("@Binding from @State").tag(0)
                Text("Custom @Binding").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                if tab == 0 {
                    Text("When you tap a button, a view below should not be updated. That's a desired behaviour.")
                    InsideView(value: $someValue)
                } else if tab == 1 {
                    Text("When you tap a button, a view below will be updated (its background color will be set to random value to indicate this). This is unexpected because the view State has not changed.")
                    InsideView(value: customBinding)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
            
            Button("Tap! Count: \(count)") {
                count += 1
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 350)
        .padding()
    }
}




struct InsideView: View {
    
    @Binding var value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        print("[⚠️] InsideView body.")
        
        return VStack {
            Text("I'm a child view. My body should be called only once.")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("Value: \(value)")
        }
        .background(Color.random)
    }
    
}



extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
    static var random: Color {
        Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: But when you update the outer view (which calls the body of the outer view), shouldn’t that automatically also update the body of the inner view?

Comment: Well, no, I don't think it should. And it's not what happens for most of the views. If that was true, any change in the top-most container would mean a cascade of updates to all the children views which would lead to a disastrous performance. Outer view state is updated and so it's body is called. But the arguments passed to Inner View stay the same thus should not be updated.

Comment: Yea, you're right, I see your point. Thou I cannot replicate the issue. The text "InsideView body." is only called once for me (at least in simulator / when running it with Xcode). It is correctly called multiple times in the second tab. What device/environment are you trying this on?

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I'm running it as a macOS app. Perhaps it's only a macOS issue that's not present on iOS? @Schottky

Comment: That‘s what I thought initially but I tried it on both platforms (iOS and macOS) and I can’t replicate it. I‘ll try some more though

Comment: Oh damn, maybe that's because I'm on macOS Monterey beta? And building with Xcode 13. I'll check if I can replicate the issue when building with Xcode 12.

Comment: That might very well be the case. I tried this on macOS Big Sur, not the Beta (Xcode 12) and the latest (but not beta) iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm i think the reason is being updated is because you are using a computed property in the ContentView view. and even if it's not tagged with a state annotation like @State, @Binding,@Stateobject... its a view state regardless, and swiftui use that to infer the difference between a view with an old state and a new state. And you're getting a new binding object at every contentview body update.

you can try change the init from what you have to something like this

```
let customBinding: Binding<Int>

init() {
    self.customBinding = Binding<Int> { 99 } set: { _ in }
}
```

but i would advise against this approach because simply is not useful to create a binding like this in the view, because you can't change anything inside the set because it's the init of a struct.

Instead you can pass in the init an ObservableObject where you moved the state logic to an ObservableObject and use that.
something like this

```
class ContentViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someValue: Int = 100
    var customBinding: Binding<Int> = .constant(0)
    
    init() {
        customBinding = Binding<Int> { [weak self] in
            self?.someValue ?? 0
        }
        set: { [weak self] in
            self?.someValue = $0
        }
    }
}
// and change the InsideView like 
struct InsideView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var state: ContentViewState
    @Binding var value: Int

    init(state: ContentViewState) {
        self.state = state
        _value = state.customBinding
    }
...
}
```

I would still use the `$` with simple @state notation most of the time where i don't have complicated states to handle, but this can be another approach i guess.